# Smartwatch 2 - Cannot compile sample project even

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt, sony-smartwatch

I wanted to start developing for the Sony Smartwatch 2 I just got.
This is where the problems started. I found many official articles about downloading and setting up the Sony Add-on SDK.

But here's the dark side:
It is not available anymore from Sony's dev site, so I could not add it by using the Android SDK manager .

After lots of sweat I managed to find it only [here](http://www.csdn.net/article/a/2013-10-29/15816989).

Which is the 2.0 version.
I unzipped it into my `/[SDK]/add-ons/sony_add-on_sdk_2_0` folder, and set up Eclipse (4.6.3) with the following SDK manager settings:
[SDK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOIC6.png)

First it reported the Sony SDK broken, but I found in another topic that I should add a `source.properties` file, in order to make it work, which has the following header:

```
### Android Tool: Source of this archive.
#Wed Feb 28 14:14:39 CET 2018
Addon.NameDisplay=SONY ADD-On SDK
Addon.NameId=sony_add_on
Addon.VendorDisplay=SONY
Addon.VendorId=sony
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=16
Pkg.Desc=Android + Google APIs
```

Then it became visible for the Eclipse

When I try to build the `SamplePreferenceActivity` it is imported with `SmartExtensionsAPI` and `SmartExtensionsUtils` but one after the other as I read this can make errors too, in the following order:

1. API
2. Utils
3. Sample

which has the following properties:
[Properties for SmartExtensionAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRiMm.png)

[Properties for SmartExtensionUtils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IbCU.png)

With these settings I still get error in:
`/SmartExtensionUtils/src/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/extension/util/widget/NotificationWidgetExtension.java`

saying

> `SmartWatchNotificationWidgetImage` cannot be resolved to a type

and in

```
/SamplePreferenceActivity/res/layout/item_gallery.xml
```

saying:

> Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.ActionMode Couldn't
>   resolve resource @dimen/smart_watch_2_control_width You must supply a
>   layout_width attribute. Couldn't resolve resource
>   @dimen/smart_watch_2_text_size_large
>   "@dimen/smart_watch_2_text_size_large" in attribute "textSize" is not
>   a valid format. Couldn't resolve resource
>   @dimen/smart_watch_2_text_size_medium
>   "@dimen/smart_watch_2_text_size_medium" in attribute "textSize" is not
>   a valid format.

What am I missing here? Should I use a completely different setup? Is this because I had to manually add the SDK to Eclipse? If you need anything else to understand the problem properly, feel free to ask me, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Have you checked whether smartwatch 3 API still supports previous version of devices? Have you tried contacting official source to ask why the API links are gone?

Comment: As far as I know, Sony Add-on SDK 2.0 is the API for Smartwatch 2, so it should be compatible. I haven't contacted official source yet, as I heard they take too long to answer, but I will, you're right.